# Форматирование в TextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Есть TextView, нужно вывести отформатированный текст, как в примере, который я прикрепил ниже.

Первые строки делаю с помощью `NSMutableAttributedString`, `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, `NSTextTab`. Все работает, как надо.

Проблема заключается в последней строке "О направлении ...". Как сделать так чтобы с определенного расстояния строка обрезалась и вывод продолжался на новой строке, но при этом другая строка шла справой стороны?

[image: Пример]

Comment: Покажи на рисунке как должно быть

Comment: @MaximBogdanov Показывать не буду, потому что пришел к выводу что такую верстку в UITextView сделать нельзя (без каких-то жестких костылей). Я говорю о том, что идет ниже "Связанные документы", все что выше отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: Скорей всего можно, потому что внутри UITextView находится NSAttributedString

Comment: Да он там находится, это строка с атрибутами, мы можем засунуть картинку, но мы не можем разбить одну строку на разные строки и расположить их как показано выше.

Comment: 1. Зачем засовывать картинку в текст?

Comment: 2. Как выше это как?

Comment: Вообще смысл следующий - находишь место в котором тебе надо сделать перенос. На первую линию ставишь одни атрибуты (выравнивание влево), на остальные - другие атрибуты (выравнивание вправо). Но так как ты не рассказал подробнее что тебе надо, то не уверен что это то что ты хочешь

Comment: Это костыль, но даже он не подходит, потому что это разные строки и мы не знаем, когда будет перенос, а когда нет. Запускается это все на разных экранах, на одном может вместиться на другом нет. Гору велосипедов лепить не хочется, но за идею ty.

Comment: Когда перенос легко определить - Ширина textview доступна и метод есть в nsstring вроде сколько текст занимает точек с учётом шрифта

Comment: Это костыль) это нам не подходит